# Slope of multidimensional line in regression

Tags: machine-learning, regression, slope

lets say I did a regression problem and I got weights = [w0,w1,w2,...wn], with n a large number.

How do we find the Slope of this line?

I know how to do slopes in 2D, but I'm having difficulty figuring this out.

Thanks

*Sorry if this is too basic for you.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is not clear. What is your input? What do you expect as an output?

Comment: @Andrei Hi: I had a Nx1 y (label) array, and a nxD x(feature array). I did linear regression and I got the array W (weights) that can be used for prediction. Ynew= xnew.W.
Now, the questions asks about the slope of this line.

Comment: Is the regression line $y=w_0+w_1x_1+w_2x_2+\ldots + w_nx_n$?

Comment: @callculus42 yes.

Comment: That is an equation of a hyperplane in an n-dimensional space. Slope is defined only in one dimension. The generalization of this is a gradient. If you really want, you can define the slope along a certain direction.

Comment: @Gaussianlover Here you have $n$ partial slopes $(w_1, w_2, \ldots , w_n)$.

Comment: The question wants the slope as a single float value. 
If it helps, in another questions it want the slope of the first principal component after PCA. Slope of a vector?

Comment: @Gaussianlover Can you post the whole exercise, word by word?

Comment: @callculus42, sorry for the delay. Unfortunately, the assignment says we are not allowed to post them online. However after discussing with TAs. they told me for testing our code they use a single x, so we would be in 2D and slope makes sense now. Sorry for the confusion. Thank you